# Can I constrain a generic parameter to *not* be optional?

Tags: swift, generics

Let's say I have this code:

```
func hello<T>(thing: T) -> String {
    return "hello \(thing)"
}
```

Can I write a version of the `hello` function that won't compile if it's passed an optional?

```
let foo = "some"
let bar: String? = nil

print(helloNoOptional(foo))  // should compile
print(helloNoOptional(bar))  // should not compile
```

I'm thinking maybe it's doable with a protocol conformance or `where` clause on T but I can't think of how exactly that would work.

The reason I want to do this is because I'm dealing with a actual function in legacy codebase that has no sensible behavior if `thing` is nil. So I'd rather prevent `hello` from being called on an optional rather than deal with unwrapping `thing` inside of hello and trying to figure out a sensible error behavior.

**Update:**

A possible path...I realized that the Optional enum conforms to the `NilLiteralConvertible` protocol. So if I can find a way to constrain my generic to **not** conform to a type, I can exclude optionals de facto. But I don't know if it's possible to do something like

```
<T where !T: NilLiteralConvertible>
```

Comment: I'm not quite clear on the requirement. What kind of function can take "literally anything at all, with no restrictions at all, except one specific enum called Optional?" Optional has a little bit of language magic, but for the most part, it's just an enum type. My suspicion is that what you really want to do is create a protocol that you can attach to the types you *do* accept, rather than "anything but Optional."

Comment: "Literally anything at all, with no restrictions at all, except one specific enum called Optional" is pretty much exactly what I want (or more precisely, anything at all except for 'nil'). I'm guessing when you phrase it that way it's not possible without some kind of dependent types but wanting to constrain a type to hold only specific values is turning out to be a pretty common use case for me.

Comment: It's not clear how your function can work on "any value except nil." What does it do? nil isn't really magical in Swift. It's a legitimate value (`Optional.None`). It isn't 0 or NULL or anything like that. You can generically work with nil exactly like you can work on any other enum value. It isn't in itself dangerous like in other languages.

Comment: In the particular case that prompted this question, some legacy code has a function that interpolates T into a string and then uploads the string to a server. It never makes business-logic sense to put a nil value (or "Optional.Some("Thing")" into the string so if the programmer is doing it (as the legacy code was) it's definitely a mistake. I can probably do something like re-write the function to check for nil and optional and noop if necessary but I'd rather prevent programmer mistakes by enforcing the business logic using the compiler (if that's possible).

Comment: @rogueleaderr Have you had time to see if the solution I've proposed below works out for you?

Answer (score 5):

Best I can think of is overload and check at runtime:

```
func hello<T>(thing: T) -> String {
    return "hello \(thing)"
}

fun hello<T>(thing: T?) -> String {
    fatalError("No optionals allowed!")
}

hello("swift")  // fine
hello(2)        // fine
hello(Int("2")) // fatal error
```

But I don't know of a way of generating a compile-time error instead.

Comment: We can add `@available(swift, deprecated: 2)` on top of the function to make compiler emit warning

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

You can create a dummy protocol (`NotOfOptionalType` below) and extend all types you expect to use in your generic functions by this protocol. Finally use the dummy protocol as a type constraint for the parameter(s) in your generic functions; optionals does not meet this type constraint and you'll be given an error at compile time if they are sent as parameters for these functions.

```
// dummy protocol
protocol NotOfOptionalType {}

extension String : NotOfOptionalType {}
extension Int : NotOfOptionalType {}
extension Double : NotOfOptionalType {}
// ... extend to the types you will use

func hello<T: NotOfOptionalType > (thing: T) -> String {
    return "hello \(thing)"
}

let foo = "some"
var bar: String? = nil

print(hello(foo))  // compiles
print(hello(bar))  // fails at compile time
bar = "something"
print(hello(bar))  // fails at compile time
print(hello(bar!)) // compiles
```

Comment: I like the idea but I just tried it and hello(bar) does compile but the cast fails at *runtime* not compile time. So it doesn't prevent the programmer `self.shootFoot()` I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Airspeed Velocity's answer, I personally prefer to keep everything in one place, like so...

```
func hello<T>(_ thing: T) -> String {
    
    if T.self is ExpressibleByNilLiteral.Type {
        fatalError("Optional types not supported")
    }

    return "hello \(thing)"
}
```